# Showing that a matrix is normalised

Tags: matrices

I 've recently come across a question which asks to show that a 2x2 matrix is normalised. The matrix looked as follows and is supposed to represent a linear polariser:
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$

Now I know that for vectors show that it's the magnitude $|V| = \sqrt{V^{T}V} = 1$ ($V^T$ being the transpose of $V$), however I don't really know what the equivalent definition for a matrix is. I was hoping someone might explain it to me.

Comment: It would be good to get some more context. Were there more parts to this question? Was there some kind of matrix norm involved, perhaps?

Comment: Generally, something must be normalized with respect to something else (like vectors are with respect to some norm and/or scalar product), anyways there is the non-negligible possibility that a linguistic barrier made you confuse the adjective *normal* with *normalised*.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, the question first asked to "calculate the matrix for a horizontal polariser" and then specifically said to "show that the matrix is normalised". It is possible that its a problem with the wording of the question more so than my understanding of it, unfortunately this rarely turns out to be the case so I thought I should ask.